# Error when sudo apt-get install php5-cli

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm using linux mint. I'm trying to install php5-cli, but after execution a corresponding bash command I've the following log:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-cli is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 353 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up php5-common (5.4.6-1ubuntu1.5) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing php5-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up man-db (2.6.3-1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing man-db (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php5:
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on php5-common (= 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.5); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cli:
 php5-cli depends on php5-common (= 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.5); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing php5-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-common
 man-db
 libapache2-mod-php5
 php5-cli
E: Sub-
```

process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

If I'm trying to execute sudo apt-get install man-db or sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 I have the same errors. Why it occurred?

Comment: Perhaps this link might help: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2105825.html

Comment: @Siddhartha YEAH!!! It helps. After php installation there is no php.load and php.conf in apache2/modules dir. sudo apt-get -f libapache2-mod-php5 is correct this error. Many thanks!

Comment: Haha I just googled your error! Glad to be of help.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Do you mean: sudo apt-get install -f libapache2-mod-php5 ???

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error after symlinking the /etc/php5/cli/php.ini from /etc/php5/apache/php.ini
I deleted the symlink and then called

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

all is good!

Answer (score 1):

before above you should do

```
sudo mv /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.bak
```