# After update Ubuntu server error accord with apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I tried to update my server, so I run the following command via ssh:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I get the following error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
       php5-cli
       php5-readline
       php-pear
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I searched a lot for a solution to my problem but couldn't find a suitable one that helps me.

What do I have to do to fix it?

***Edit:***

Thanks to Sohail Answer I did the following:

```
sudo mv /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.bak
sudo apt-get install -f
```

now i dont get my pages via http as you can see in the root it display me list of nothing:

```
http://ec2-54-84-227-22.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
```

and in the index.html page (that I see him via ssh) it give me page not found:

```
http://ec2-54-84-227-22.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.html
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: not exactly thanks to you i found:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354602/error-when-sudo-apt-get-install-php5-cli

and there 'sudo mv /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.bak' < that helped me with the issue

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Sohail Answer i did the following:

```
sudo mv /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.bak
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then ic hanged the following line in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

by

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

that solve my problem.